# Browser loading width/height value that is NOT on CSS File

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

As you can see from the image below, the browser (both Chrome and Firefox) insists on applying width:24px / height 24px for the icon.

[image]

However, I have already changed the values on the CSS file. In fact, if you click on the file the browser says the width/height are coming from, the browser inspector itself show the updated values of width:150/height:40, as the image below shows.

[image]

So basically the inspector is contradicting itself! I can't solve this clearing the cache.

Any ideas on what is going on? Could it be related to this being a .scss file?

You can check it live here: https://www.chatbotforums.com/ . I am trying to change the size of the Facebook login icon, inside the "Welcome" box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

For some reason the browser inspector was saying that the width/height were being pulled from the _style.scss file, but that was not the case.

They were being pulled from another file, the standard style.css, so I had to tweak the values there instead.

Strangely this incorrect information appeared on inspectors of both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Your banner is overflowing. You will have to modify the CSS for the box container and then the icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. I found the problem (see my answer). I will fix the overflow now.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `width` and `height` style to `min-width` and `min-height`.

```css
img {
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.ca/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico">
```

Comment: Didn't work here. The browser keeps using the 24px (which is the old value).

Comment: Can you provide some resource To HTML and CSS